# The text is no longer sent to the client

Tags: c, linux, tcp, pthreads

In my code i try to do a little game (Nim) for a school project. So i use a server tcp and 2 threads to send info to the 2 clients.
I program step by step and i stuck here cause the client (on the th1 thread) doesn't display or receive the string "Joueur 1 entrez un nombre (1-3) : " in the function takeCoin.

server code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define false 0 
#define true  1

int J[2] = {-1, -1};
int nCoin = 15;


sem_t semaphore;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int cree_socket_tcp_ip()
 {
  int sock;
  struct sockaddr_in adresse;
  if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "Erreur socket\n");
    return -1;
   }
  memset(&adresse, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  adresse.sin_family = AF_INET;
  adresse.sin_port = htons(8080);
  inet_aton("Localhost", &adresse.sin_addr);
  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &adresse, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
   {
    close(sock);
    fprintf(stderr, "Erreur bind\n");
    return -1;
   }
  return sock;
 }

void initCoin(char tab[])
{
   tab[0] = '|';
   tab[1] = ' ';
   tab[2] = ' ';
   tab[3] = ' ';
   tab[4] = ' ';
   for (int i = 5; i < 5 + nCoin;i++)
   {
     tab[i] = 'O';
   }
   tab[nCoin + 5] = ' ';
   tab[nCoin + 6] = ' ';
   tab[nCoin + 7] = ' ';
   tab[nCoin + 8] = ' ';
   tab[nCoin + 9] = '|';
   tab[nCoin + 10] = '\n';
   tab[nCoin + 11] = '\0';
}

void takeCoin(int sock, int coin)
{
   char tCoin[3]; 
   char tab[100];
   int valid = false;
   printf("In fonction takeCoin.\n");
   while (valid == false)
   {
      if (J[0] == sock)
      {
        sprintf(tab,"Joueur 1 entrez un nombre (1-3) : ");
        write(sock,tab,strlen(tab));
      }
      else
      {
        sprintf(tab,"Joueur 2 entrez un nombre (1-3) : ");
        write(sock,tab,strlen(tab));
      }
      recv(sock,tCoin,3,0);
      printf("tCoin : %s\n",tCoin);
      coin = atoi(tCoin);
      if ((coin > 0) && (coin <= 3))
      valid = true;
      else
      {
      sprintf(tab,"Le nombre doit être entre 1 et 3 bord inclus.\n");
      write(sock,tab,46*sizeof(char));
      }
   }
}
 
void *func_j1(void *arg)
{
   int sock = *((int *)arg);
   int coin;
   int nCoinT;
   char tab[100];
   char tCoin[3]; 
   sprintf(tab,"Jeux des pièces.\n"); 
   write(sock,tab,strlen(tab));
   
   
   sprintf(tab,"Vous etes le joueur 1.\n");
   write(sock,tab,strlen(tab)); 
   
   
   sprintf(tab,"Attende du joueur 2.\n");
   write(sock,tab,strlen(tab)); 
   sem_wait(&semaphore);
   
   
   sprintf(tab,"joueur 2 Trouver.\n");
   write(sock,tab,strlen(tab));
  
   
   sprintf(tab,"La partie commence.\n");
   write(sock,tab,strlen(tab));
   
   
   initCoin(tab);
   write(sock,tab,strlen(tab));
      
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   nCoinT = nCoin;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   while (nCoinT >= 2)
   {
     
     takeCoin(sock, coin);
   }
   close(sock);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *func_j2(void *arg)
{
   int sock = *((int *)arg);
   int nCoinT;
   int coin;
   char tab[100];
   sprintf(tab,"Jeux des pièces.\n"); 
   write(sock,tab,strlen(tab));
   sem_post(&semaphore);
   
   sprintf(tab,"Vous etes le joueur 2.\n");
   write(sock,tab,strlen(tab)); 
   
   sprintf(tab,"La partie commencer.\n");
   write(sock,tab,strlen(tab));
   
   initCoin(tab);
   write(sock,tab,strlen(tab));
   
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   nCoinT = nCoin;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   
   while (nCoinT >= 2)
   {
     sprintf(tab,"Le joueur 1 est en train de jouer.\n");
     write(sock,tab,strlen(tab));
     sem_wait(&semaphore);
     //takeCoin(sock, coin);
   } 
   close(sock);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int affiche_adresse_socket(int sock)
 {
  struct sockaddr_in adresse;
  socklen_t longueur;
  longueur = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  if (getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&adresse, &longueur) < 0)
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "Erreur getsockname\n");
    return -1;
   }
  printf("IP = %s, Port = %u\n", inet_ntoa(adresse.sin_addr), ntohs(adresse.sin_port));
  return 0;
 }
 

int main(void)
 {
  int sock_contact;
  int sock_connectee;
  int j;
  pthread_t th1;
  pthread_t th2;
  struct sockaddr_in adresse;
  socklen_t longueur;
  sock_contact = cree_socket_tcp_ip();
  
  if (sock_contact < 0)
  return -1;
  listen(sock_contact, 5);
  printf("Mon adresse (sock contact) -> ");
  affiche_adresse_socket(sock_contact);
  sem_init (&semaphore, 0, 0);
  
  while (1)
   {
    printf("Attende d'un client.\n");
    longueur = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    sock_connectee = accept(sock_contact, (struct sockaddr*)&adresse, &longueur);
    printf("Client trouver.\n");
    printf("Client socket : %d\n",sock_connectee);
    J[j] = sock_connectee;
    if (j == 0)
      pthread_create(&th1, NULL, func_j1, &sock_connectee);
    else
      pthread_create(&th2, NULL, func_j2, &sock_connectee);
    j++;
  }
return 0;
}
```

client code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256


int cree_socket_tcp_client(int argc, char** argv)
 {
  struct sockaddr_in adresse;
  int sock;
  if (argc != 3)
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s adresse port\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
   }
  if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "Erreur socket\n");
    return -1;
   }

  memset(&adresse, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  adresse.sin_family = AF_INET;
  adresse.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
  inet_aton(argv[1], &adresse.sin_addr);
  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &adresse, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
   {
    close(sock);
    fprintf(stderr, "Erreur connect\n");
    return -1;
   }
  return sock;
 }
 
 void *fRecv(void *arg)
 {
   int sock = *((int *)arg);
   int len;
   char msg[100];
   while((len = recv(sock,msg,100,0)) > 0) 
   {
        msg[len] = '\0';
        printf("%s",msg);
  }
 }
 
 void *fSend(void *arg)
 {
   int sock = *((int *)arg);
   int len;
   char msg[100];
   while (1)
   {
     fgets(msg,100,stdin);
     len = write(sock,msg,strlen(msg));
     if(len < 0) 
       printf("\n message not sent \n");
   }
   
 }
 
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
    int sock=cree_socket_tcp_client(argc, argv);
    int i = 0;
    pthread_t tRecv;
    pthread_t tSend;
    char tab[100];
    char tab2[100];
    char fin[4] ="fin";
    
    pthread_create(&tRecv, NULL, fRecv, &sock);
    pthread_create(&tSend, NULL, fSend, &sock);
    pthread_join(tRecv, NULL);
    close(sock);
  }
```

I program on a virtual machine, I don't know if it matters.

Comment: This is tagged `c`, but you take a reference: `takeCoin(int sock,int &coin)`. This might be valid in `c++`, so, _what_ language are you using? If `c`, the syntax is not valid.

Comment: In the server, `inet_aton("Localhost", &adresse.sin_addr);` is wrong. When you print the address later, it comes back as `0.0.0.0` [instead of `127.0.0.1`]. Find the correct call to convert that. For now, just do: `inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &adresse.sin_addr);` Compile with `-Wall` and fix _all_ warnings. In server, `j` is unitialized, so `J[j]` segfaults. This may be a bit too complex for your first client/server program, so try to simplify a bit. I'm not sure why you need two threads in each program.

Comment: sry for the reference i just test the function and i added at the last moment.
It's a mistake. @CraigEstey

Comment: the project requires to use a server and to make exchanges at least between two clients.
After i don't know if the game i try to make is too hard for me.

Comment: 'pthread_create(&th1, NULL, func_j1, &sock_connectee);' - sock_connectee may get overwritten by another incoming accept before the thread can dereference it.

Comment: 'recv(sock,tCoin,3,0);' etc.  You must correctly and completely handle the results returned by system calls like send(), recv().

Comment: 'recv(sock,tCoin,3,0);' etc - may return 1, 2 or 3.  TCP is a byte stream and, by itself, cannot guarantee to transfer messages longer than one byte per recv call.  You must design accordingly.

Comment: 'msg[len] = '\0';' writes out-of-bounds if 100 bytes are received.

Comment: ' printf("tCoin : %s\n",tCoin);' tCoin is not guaranteed NUL-terminated.